# Is it possible to use a Canon TR 4500 printer with only a black ink cartridge and without a color ink cartridge?

Tags: windows-7, printer, canon-pixma, ink

When both the black ink cartridge and the color ink cartridge are in the printer, I see that the black ink cartridge has some ink remaining:

[image]

However,  as soon as I remove  the color ink cartridge, the printer refuses to print:

[image]

I use a Canon TR 4500 printer with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Is it possible to use a Canon TR 4500 printer with only a black ink cartridge and without a color ink cartridge?

Comment: You answered it yourself : No.

Comment: Unless the software allows this, you cannot. Older printers allowed this but not anymore, they now force you to buy ink.

Comment: @harrymc there could be some setting allowing users not to have a color ink cartridge.

Comment: @Moab yes I wonder if the software allows this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great [answer](https://qr.ae/pN0qcK) from [Stephen Maestas](https://www.quora.com/profile/Stephen-Maestas) (Technical Support at Canon 2015-present):

> No. All cartridges must be installed. That being said, you may operate a TR4500 printer with an empty color cartridge installed. All you have to do is to hold down the “stop” button for about 8 seconds and that will dismiss the low or empty ink warning and allows you to continue printing with the black tank. If you are using Windows or Mac OS, you can go into the maintenence section of the drivers and tell your computer to print in black only. This will cause colored images to be printed black only.